# Drawing a meshed ellipse with tikz-feynman

Tags: shapes, tikz-feynman

Is it possible, by using tikz-feynman, to draw a mashed ellipse such as (the appearance can also be similar to the deformed blob):

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=grid] (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: gridded ellipse]